# Displaying possible elements from list of list within the range of input floats

Tags: python, list

Let's say i have a list of list containing:

```
L = [['10.2','9.1','G'],['12.9','7.4','H'],['5.6','4.3','G'],['5.7','4.5','G']]
```

where the alphabets in each list within the list of list represents something like 'type'

In this case, python will request for the user input of four float numbers separated by ':', for example;

```
input = 5.5:4.4:5.7:4.7
```

Before python proceed on dealing with the input, as shown in the list of list, the alphabets in each list at the third section represents a type therefore;

For example, upon user input, python will compare the number of the input to the values in the list of list within the range of the user input of **type 'G'**.

Hence, python will **output the list** from the list of list in which the numbers are **in range** as the **user input**. So,

```
input = 5.5:4.4:5.7:4.6

output = [5.6,4.3] and [5.7,4.5]
```

## note: the input consist of four float numbers separated by ':' and we can assume the first half is a set 5.5:4.4 and the second half is a set 5.7:4.6.

I gave it a try but i don't know how i would be able to output the list within range to the input.

```
L = [['10.2','9.1','G'],['12.9','7.4','H'],['5.6','4.3','G'],['5.8','4.5','G']]

userinput = input("Enter floats:")     #example 5.5:4.4:5.7:4.6
strSeparate = userinput.split(':')     
floatInput = [float(i) for i in strSeparate]   #turn input into float
inputList = [floatInput[:2],floatInput[2:]]    #[[5.5,4.4],[5.7,4.6]]

for line in L:
   for val in inputList:#???
```

output format would be:

```
[[5.6,4.3],[5.7,4.5]]
```

Comment: can you please explain what is the output format which you are expecting ??

Comment: `5.8` is out of range (`5.5:4.4:5.7:4.6`). Why it's in the result?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry bout that,my mistake. I corrected it in the recent edit.

Comment: again, `4.3` is out of range `5.5:4.4:5.7:4.6`. Otherwise, it should be treated as search if ANY number of nested array is in user's range

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below.

First the user input is split on the `:`, the values are converted to floats, and an iterator is created to help pair the values with `zip()`. Then each pair is compared with the ranges in `L`. A pair lies within the range if both of its values lie between the upper and lower values of the range. Any pair that lies within the range is added to the `results` list.

```
L = [['10.2','9.1','G'],['12.9','7.4','H'],['5.6','4.3','G'],['5.8','4.5','G']]

inputs = [float(s) for s in '5.5:4.4:5.7:4.6'.split(':')]
it = iter(inputs)

results = []

for pair in zip(it, it):
    for line in L:
        if line[2] == 'G':
            upper = float(line[0])
            lower = float(line[1])
            if ((lower <= pair[0] <= upper) and
                (lower <= pair[1] <= upper)):
                results.append([upper, lower])

print(results)
```

This will output:

```
[[5.6, 4.3], [5.8, 4.5]]
```

Note that this code will include duplicate values in `results` if there is more than one input pair that fall within a range. If this is not wanted you can use a `set` instead of a `list` for `results`, and add *tuples* to the set (because lists are not hashable).

Also this assumes that the upper and lower bounds for each sub list in `L` is in order (upper then lower). If that's not the case you can do this:

```
            upper = float(line[0])
            lower = float(line[1])
            lower, upper = lower, upper if lower <= upper else upper, lower
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [***numpy.arange()***](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy.arange) and [***numpy.any()***](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) funcions:

```
import numpy as np

L = [['10.2','9.1','G'],['12.9','7.4','H'],['5.6','4.3','G'],['5.7','4.5','G']]
userinput = "5.5:4.4:5.7:4.6"     #example 5.5:4.4:5.7:4.6
floatInput = [float(i) for i in userinput.split(':')]   #turn input into float

result = []
for i in (floatInput[0:2], floatInput[2:]):
    r = np.arange(i[1], i[0], 0.1)   # generating float numbers range
    items = [l[0:2] for l in L
             if isinstance(np.any([r[r >= float(l[0])], r[r >= float(l[1])]]), np.ndarray)
             and l[0:2] not in result]

    if (items): result.extend(items)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['5.6', '4.3'], ['5.7', '4.5']]
```